# How to set target element by jQuery?

Tags: javascript, css, modal-dialog

I set target to element `"div id='login'"` manual from URL `somesite:8080/#login`.
How can I do it by jQuery automatic on page load?

Comment: Uh, what? You want to set the location hash on pageload? If so it's just `window.location.hash = 'login'`

Comment: @adeneo this would require an anchor with id near the element

Comment: @adeneo but it make page request on server? i just want to do it in client.

Comment: @xcezzz - I have no idea what you  mean at all ?

Comment: @vmduan - that is clientside code, it's javascript ?

Comment: @adele it work! thank you, how do i confirm your help is useful?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the hash (target) part of the URL by setting the `window.location.hash` property.  For example:

```
window.location.hash = 'login';
```